# Content is not downloaded when generating a file downloadable with php

Tags: php, download

I'm making something that generates a text file with text inside, but whenever I download the file, all I get is `<h` inside the file, and no content in it. This is my code:

```
$filename = 'download.txt';
$content = "Hi";
$f = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($f, $content);
fclose($f);
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

should filesize("$filename") be filesize($filename)?

Comment: That does nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=gen.txt');
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

Comment: Nope, It still downloads with `<h` as the content on the file

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the directory where you want to save the file like `$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/filename.txt","w");`

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and pasted it into a file and run it and the 'download.txt' file was created and contained "Hi"

So it's not your code, it may be your web server setup.

Comment: Do I need to have download.txt saved on my server?

Comment: fclose($f);
this saves it on the server. If you can not see the file on the server then for some reason or another you are not saving it. You need to check what is the result of all your assignments. Are you really getting a file object when you create the file. What is the result from your write command and what is the result of the close command. Not checking for errors is fine when you know what you are doing, but if you are just learning by copying and pasting someone else's code you really need to add all the checks that you can.